# In Lua, how do I prevent a program from crashing, after a user left an value blank, which the program needs to calculate?

Tags: lua, crash

I wanted to create a program for me and friends, which calculates a value.
However I also wanted to make the program uncrashable, so my friends dont tell me how they broke my code.

So the problem is that they could leave this: `d = io.read()`
blank resulting the program to crash once it wants to calculate `d`.

So how do I stop them from leaving `d` blank or entering a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it so it defaults to 0

```
local d = tonumber(io.read()) or 0
```